# error: expected primary-expression before || token

Tags: c++, tokens

Estoy aprendiendo a programar y me dieron este ejercicio:
Basado en los 2 ejercicios anteriores, hacer un programa para ingresar por teclado la
longitud de los tres lados de un triángulo y luego listar que tipo de triángulo es:

- Equilátero: si los tres lados son iguales
- Isósceles: si dos de los tres lados son iguales
- Escaleno: si los tres lados son distintos entre sí

El código que escribí es el siguiente pero me tira error y no sé cómo resolverlo, ¿Alguien podría ayudarme?

```
using namespace std;


int main(){
    int n1,n2,n3;
    cout<<"Ingrese tres numeros: ";
    cin>>n1;
    cin>>n2;
    cin>>n3;
    if((n1==n2)&&(n2==n3)){
        cout<<"Equilatero. ";
        cout<<endl;
    }
    else{
        if((n1==n2)&&(n1!=n3))||((n1==n3)&&(n1!=n2))||((n2==n3)&&(n2!=n1)){
                cout<<"Isosceles."
        else{
            cout<<"Escaleno."
        }

        }
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Tu problema está en como escribes el bloque `if`, nota que cierras los parentesis de condición antes de tiempo (exactamente después de `(n1==n2)&&(n1!=n3)`)

Prueba agregar un parentesis extra al principio (lo separo para que sea mas claro):

```cpp
if(
 ((n1==n2)&&(n1!=n3)) || ((n1==n3)&&(n1!=n2)) || ((n2==n3)&&(n2!=n1))
)
```

Tambien te sugiero que revises como abres y cierras las llaves `{}`